# Optimizing Python script that executes SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have a script that parses information out of csv file and executes SQL statements to create a table and insert the data. I have to parse a ~25 GB csv file, but with my current script I would estimate that could take up to 20 days judging from previous sized files I have parsed. Any suggestions on how to optimize my script so that it runs faster? I left out the createtable function due to the fact it's only called once. InsertRow() is the function I think I really need to make faster. Thanks in advance.

```
#Builds sql insert statements and executes sqlite3 calls to insert the rows 
def insertRow(cols):
    first = True; #First value for INSERT arguments doesn't need comma front of it.
    conn = sqlite3.connect('parsed_csv.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    print cols
    insert = "INSERT INTO test9 VALUES("
    for col in cols:
        col = col.replace("'", "")
        if(first):
            insert +=  "'" + col + "'"
            first = False;
        else:
            insert += "," + "'" + col+ "'" + " "
    insert += ")"
    print (insert)
    c.execute(insert)
    conn.commit()


def main():
    #Get rid of first argument (filename)
    cmdargs = sys.argv[1:]
    #Convert values to integers
    cmdargs = list(map(int, cmdargs))

    #Get headers
    with open(r'requests_fields.csv','rb') as source:
        rdr = csv.reader(source)
        for row in rdr:          
             createTable(row[:], cmdargs[:])

    with open(r'test.csv','rb') as source:
        rdr= csv.reader( source )
        for row in rdr:
            #Clear contents of list
            outlist =[]
            #Append all rows onto list and then write to row in output csv file
            for index in cmdargs:
                outlist.append(row[index])
            insertRow(outlist[:])
```

Could the slow speed I'm experiencing possibly have to due with creating a connection each time to the database in insertRow()?

Comment: Apart from that: indent your code properly

Comment: I think you can import csv to sqlite directly without needing a script like this: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a database and not sqlite for 25GB of data?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use batch inserts that most _real_ databases support.

Comment: @MrE I originally was doing it that way. Unfortunately, I need to parse out only certain columns and I couldn't figure out how to insert specific columns and ignore other columns that way.

Comment: @user1153018 you could first bulk-import into a temporary and then select the columns you want (with sql...) into the final table

Comment: Probably a better fit for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Python, SQLLite, 25 GB. Fastspeed = fantastic.

2) **insert = "INSERT INTO test9 VALUES("** - it wrong solution. Good style is [using parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

```
insert = "INSERT INTO test9 (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
c.execute(insert, [value1, value2, value3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to the database and creating a cursor for each row. If you move this step outside of the loop it will be much faster.

You're also commiting after each row. If it fits the logic of your application I would suggest also trying reducing the frequency that this happens, although at the other extreme doing the entire 25GB file in a single commit may have its own problems.